# Ejs independent of layout

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, ejs

I am new to using ejs. I have a layout.ejs file which works fine, but I want to have a separate webpage which is completely independent of the layout.ejs predefined layout.

How can I go about doing this?
Any suggestions/sources would be appreciated

Thank you

Comment: It's really unclear what you are asking here. Your other webpage isn't going to involve layout.ejs unless you explicitly make it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use both ejs files in a single page you can use partials and include one ejs in another